# Dynamic table name in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am able to create a table from a dynamic value, but I am unable to reference that table when I use it in a join.

```
DECLARE @UserName varchar(5)
DECLARE @EmpRacfid varchar(max)
SET @UserName = RIGHT(SYSTEM_USER,5)
SET @EmpTable = 'dbo.Employee_' + @UserName

CROSS JOIN @EmpTable emp
```

I get the following message:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Must declare the table variable "@EmpTable".

I also tried something like this, but it also failed:

```
CROSS JOIN '[dbo].[Employee_' + @UserName + ']' emp
```

I was wondering if anyone has done this, or knows if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join the dynamic table name, then you need to put your whole script in dynamic constructed sql, and use EXEC to exec the whole dynamic sql. Like following:

```
'cross join' + '[dbo].[employee_'+@UserName+'] temp' ....
```